# How to create Dynamic Action so that according to user's choice page will or will not redirect

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5.1

1. I have a Link which redirect user to another page in APEX.
   Link Attributes:

   class="new_test_run t-Button t-Button--simple t-Button--hot t-Button--stretch" title="Create Test Run" tc_id="#ID#"
2. There is also "Click" event which is run when user click mentioned link.
3. Click event has dynamic action.
4. When event is true, there is "Confirm" action with proper text.
5. Finally there is "Execute JavaScript Code" action which set a parameter:

   ```
   apex.confirm({
   request:"CREATE_TEST_RUN",
       set:{"P300_TEST_CYCLE_ID": $(this.triggeringElement).attr('tc_id')}
   });
   ```

I have come to new project and I need to take care of some APEX issues because nobody knows it. I was learning it few years ago so I am dedicated for it.

I was trying sonthing like this:

`if (confirm {
    apex_util.redirect_url(p_url=>'f?p=110:309:&SESSION.::NO:RP::');
    apex.confirm({
      request:"CREATE_TEST_RUN",
      set:{"P300_TEST_CYCLE_ID": $(this.triggeringElement).attr('tc_id')}
});
}`

Actual result is:
Not matter whether user select "OK" or "Cancel" in dialog window, page is redirected.
Expected result is:
If user select "Cancel" dialog window should be closed and nothing should happen. So I am trying to find out how to stop redirection with Dynamic Action in case of click on "Cancel" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with help from one guy from oracle community. I will share with you the solution in case someone has similar problem in future.

In the Function and Global Variable Declaration section create a function like this:

```
function askNGo(pRedirLink){  
    console.log("Redir link: " + pRedirLink);  

    apex.message.confirm( "Are you sure?", function( okPressed ) {//message according to your needs  
    if( okPressed ) {  
        apex.navigation.redirect ( pRedirLink );  
    }  
});  
}
```

In my report source I have computed a (hidden) column with Escape special characters=No that contained the link to the target page (see the documentation to the apex_page.get_url function)

```
select col1, col2..., apex_page.get_url(p_page =>300, p_items => 'P300_TEST_CYCLE_ID', p_values => tcycle.id) create_new_ur from my_table;
```

and the Target should be defined as:

Next I have edit my link like below:

Type: Link

Link type: URL

URL: `javascript:askNGo("#CREATE_NEW_URL#");`

Link Attribute -> `class="new_test_run t-Button t-Button--simple t-Button--hot t-Button--stretch" title="Create Test Run" tc_id="#ID#" create_new_url="#CREATE_NEW_URL#"`

Finally I have set "Server-side Condition" Type = Never for dynamic action which was there. This way I have not removed it bu just set to not be used.